# How to validate react hook form select field

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm able to get the value on the `onChange` function after I select any option, but an error message appears when /I try to submit the form.

My code:

```js
<div className="form-group mb-3">
    <label>Country</label>
    <Controller
        control={control}
        name="country"
        render={({ 
            field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref }
        }) => (
            <select
                className='form-control form-select'
                onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
                inputRef={register("country", { required: true })}
            >
                <option>Select Country</option>
                {
                    Country.getAllCountries().map((item) => <option value={item.isoCode} key={item.isoCode}>{item.name}</option>)
                }
            </select>
        )}
    />
    {errors.country && <span className="error-text">Country is required</span>}
</div>
```

Error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way when your using Controller from react-hook-form:

```js
<Controller
    control={control}
    name="country"
    render={({field, fieldState: {invalid}}) => (
        <>
            <label>Country</label>
            <select
               {...field} 
               className='formcontrol form select'
               onChange={({target:{value}) => {
                  changeCountry(value)
                  field.onChange(value)
               }}>
                <option>Select Country</option>
                {Country.getAllCountries().map((item) => <option
                    value={item.isoCode}
                    key={item.isoCode}>{item.name}</option>)}
            </select>
            {invalid && <span className="error-text">Country is required</span>}
        </>
    }/>
```

If you don't have any special reasons do not desagregate `field` and use the values in `fieldState` provided by `Controller` they are related to the field rendered.

Comment: I need select change value because when we choose Country, States will display based on Country.

Therefore I m using onchange

onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}

Comment: That's ok but you need to update the value of the field in the form as well. I'll update my answer please check it